# how to merge content of two columns in particular rows without shifting the rest cells of columns

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, rows

i have tab seprated input file  in which some of second column's content are space seprated thus divided between two columns  taking space as separator , for example "LEA type" belongs to same second column entirely but its divided in such a way that "LEA" comes in second columns and "type" comes in third column and similarly "Ribosomal protein L21P" is the same name should come under second column but divided into second , third and forth column.

```
1st_col     2nd_col     3rd_col    4th_col  5th_col 6th_col
tATAAAta    TBP         ~           1       
tACCAT      Ribosomal   protein     L21P    ~   2
agtACCAT    Ribosomal   protein     L21P    ~   2
ATGTActt    AP2         ~           1       
GCAACggagc  LEA         type        1       ~   1
ATGGTa      Ribosomal   protein     L21P    ~   1
ATGGTctt    Ribosomal   protein     L21P    ~   2
ATGGTaca    Ribosomal   protein     L21P    ~   1
```

desired ouput sholud be like this, so that "LEA type" should be in column two like this "LEA_type"  and position and content of other cells do not shift.

```
1st_col     2nd_col                 3rd_col 4th_col 5th_col 6th_col
tATAAAta    TBP                     ~       1
tACCAT      Ribosomal_protein_L21P  ~       2
agtACCAT    Ribosomal_protein_L21P  ~       2
ATGTActt    AP2                     ~       1
GCAACggagc  LEA_type                ~       1
ATGGTa      Ribosomal_protein_L21P  ~       1
ATGGTctt    Ribosomal_protein_L21P  ~       2
ATGGTaca    Ribosomal_protein_L21P  ~       1
```

i have tried something like this but it cause shifting others cells too.

```
 sed 's/LEA\stype/LEA_type/g' 1_com_final_2922.txt | sed 's/Ribosomal\sprotein/Ribosomal_protein/g'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not 100% clear, but based on your output shown and conditions explained, following will look for string LEA,type and Ribosomal,protein,L21P and combine them as per your shown output too.

```
awk '($2=="LEA" && $3=="type"){$2="LEA_type";$3=""} ($2=="Ribosomal" && $3=="protein" && $4=="L21P"){$2="Ribosomal_protein_L21P";$3=$4=""} 1'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
tATAAAta    TBP ~   1   Ca_00015    Ca_00015
0   0   0   0   Ca_00027    Ca_00027
atTTACCgaa  Trihelix    ~   2   Ca_00027    Ca_00027
0   0   0   0   Ca_00027    Ca_00027
0   0   0   0   Ca_00027    Ca_00027
tACCAT Ribosomal_protein_L21P   ~ 2
agtACCAT Ribosomal_protein_L21P   ~ 2
GCAACggagc LEA_type  1 ~ 1
ATGGTa Ribosomal_protein_L21P   ~ 1
ATGGTctt Ribosomal_protein_L21P   ~ 2
ATGGTaca Ribosomal_protein_L21P   ~ 1
GCAACctccc LEA_type  1 ~ 1
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution.

```
awk '
($2=="LEA" && $3=="type"){
  $2="LEA_type";
  $3=""
}
($2=="Ribosomal" && $3=="protein" && $4=="L21P"){
  $2="Ribosomal_protein_L21P";
  $3=$4=""
}
1
'  Input_file
```

**EDIT:** Since OP has changed ask a bit so changing code a bit as follows too.
Also please use awk -F"\t" in case your Input_file is TAB delimited.

```
awk '
($2=="LEA" && $3=="type"){
  $2="LEA_type";
  $3=$4="";
}
($2=="Ribosomal" && $3=="protein" && $4=="L21P"){
  $2="Ribosomal_protein_L21P";
  $3=$4="";
}
1
' Input_file | column  -t
```

Output will be as follows.

```
1st_col     2nd_col                 3rd_col  4th_col  5th_col  6th_col
tATAAAta    TBP                     ~        1
tACCAT      Ribosomal_protein_L21P  ~        2
agtACCAT    Ribosomal_protein_L21P  ~        2
ATGTActt    AP2                     ~        1
GCAACggagc  LEA_type                ~        1
ATGGTa      Ribosomal_protein_L21P  ~        1
ATGGTctt    Ribosomal_protein_L21P  ~        2
ATGGTaca    Ribosomal_protein_L21P  ~        1
```

Comment: thanks @RavinderSingh13 ,  it cant resolve the the problem as it also shifting the cells position , i just updated my example for better understanding have a look again.

Comment: yeah it works well on this sample file but when i tried to run this on actual large size  file all columns are merges together , can we put output  file separated with  tab

Comment: It should put tab for them, post little sample where it is breaking up, into your post. Ideally it should work.

Comment: ok basically what happen , when i input space separated file it works well and gives output in space separated file but when i give tab separated file it merges all columns in one, so can  we change it so it gives tab separated file when input file is tab separated.

Comment: @a.k, gotcha. Please put -F"\t" after awk and let me know, you would have tell me this before :) Let me know how it goes then.

Answer (score 0):

Here's more flexible way to do that,

```
awk '$2~/[^0-9|^~]+/{                  # search the line which $2 is not numeric nor tide
  for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){             # continue to search start from $3
    if($i~/[^0-9|^~]+/){          # if $i is not numeric nor tide
      $2=sprintf("%s_%s",$2,$i);  # substitute $2 as $2_$i 
      $i=""                       # set $i=""
    } else                        # if hit something numeric or tide, we break
      break
  }
}1'
```

Here's one-liner,

```
awk '$2~/[^0-9|^~]+/{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){ if($i~/[^0-9|^~]+/){ $2=sprintf("%s_%s",$2,$i); $i="" } else break } }1' file
```

**Edit:**

Updated the answer for the updated OP,

```
awk '$3~/[^~]/ && NR>1{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){ if($i~/[^0-9|^~]+/){ $2=sprintf("%s_%s",$2,$i); $i="" } else{$3="~"; $4=$(i+1); $i=""; $(i+1)=""; break} } }1' file5 | column -t
```

Comment: thanks @CWLiu , its doesn't solve the problem i just updated the example have a look again. thanks